# How to create UI with time and date grid for ios app

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard, ios10

I want to create something like this(refer image)

[image: Grid]

as you can see in above image, here column represents date and row representing time. User can vertically scroll for time and horizontally for date. **blank spaces will be clickable**.

I have searched for similar kind of UI, but I don't know what to search. any thoughts to implement this custom UI will be a great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea, if you want to implement a slightly simple design as displayed in your screenshot.

You can divide the complete UI in 3 small parts and design it,

1. To display "February 2017", you can addd a label.
2. TO display **DATE**, You can use **CollectionView**, which will have direction of **Horizontal** and set the content and create a logic by which you can display 31 for Month or week wise as per your need.
3. You want to display **Time** which scroll vertical, then to display that you can use **Tableview** in which time will be displayed.

> Above is the just idea by which you can create a simple UI, in which
>   as per DATE selection, Time will be displayed in tableview.

What you are looking for is a week view which is similar like this component [Calendar-UI](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui). You can take it as a reference or modify in it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the UICollectionView by subclassing UICollectionViewLayout to let UICollectionView behave the way you want.

Check this library, it may be helpful to you. Here is the [github](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCollectionViewTableLayout-iOS) link.